# Proof for a theorem on Cohomology by Tate

Tags: reference-request, group-cohomology, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

I am searching for a reference for the proof of the following theorem.

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $C$ be a $G$-module, and let $u$ be an element of $\hat{H}^2(G,C)$. Assume
that $\hat{H}^1(H,C) = 0$ for all subgroups $H$ of $G$ and that $\hat{H}^2(H,C)$ is cyclic of order $(H : 1)$ with
generator the restriction of $u$. Then the cup product with u defines an
isomorphism
$$x \mapsto x∪u: \hat{H}^r(G,Z) → \hat{H}^{r+2}(G,C)$$
for all $r ∈ \mathbb{Z}$.

I have found this theorem originally in the book Class field theory by Artin and Tate and the proof in there is there but seem to heavily depend on another theorem supposedly in the book (theorem 12 in chapter V is how it is worded) but from what I can tell it's not actually not in the book.

It would be great if you could either provide a proof or give me a place where I could find it. Thanks,

Comment: The statement I have wrote down is from http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.7459.pdf as it's slightly stronger statement than the one written in Artin and Tate but I could get away with writing less. Again this text only provides the outline of the proof and I want a full proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find this result is to search for "Tate Nakayama theorem on cohomology", since it is usually attributed to both of them.

I googled this, and found [Milne's book](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ADTnot.pdf), which gives a citation (on page 3) to Serre's *Corps Locaux*, IX.8 .   I remembered having read the proof myself somewhere, and I think this is where.  (And of course, you can look in the English version *Local fields* if you don't like to read French.)

Comment: A proof can also be found in Milne's [notes on class field theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf#page=89), Theorem 3.11. Another can be found in Theorem 3.1.5 of Neukirch, Shmidt, Wingberg's book _Cohomology of Number Fields_.